# Does V-once also apply do child nodes of the applied element?

Tags: vue.js, directive

Does V-once also apply do child nodes of the applied element?

In the documentation they say foll

> You can also perform one-time interpolations that do not update on data change by using the v-once directive, but keep in mind this will also affect any other bindings on the same node.
> -> [source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)

What does it exactly mean to be on the same node?

```
  <div  id="one" v-once>
    This will never change {{ msg }}
    <span>But will it also never change in the child node?{{ msg }}</span>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    It seems like div two is not on the same node.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes, it applies to children".